# To do some validation in the server-side when the node has been clicked in the DevExpress "ASPxTreeList" control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I tried with `treeList_OnNodeExpanded()` but it doesn't get triggered when the node has been clicked.

Is there any other way to achieve this task of getting triggered in the server-side function?

Comment: @CR41G14, This is TreeList and not the TreeView.

Comment: Why don't you contact DX guys directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ASPxTreeList.NodeExpanding](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxTreeListASPxTreeList_NodeExpandingtopic). Set `e.Cancel` to true if you want to cancel expanding.